# DataGridView.CellValueChanged

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I makethe value of a cell change when the value of a combobox cell changes in a datagridview?

[When the value of column "producto" changes, then change the "precio" column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hj3H.png)

```
    private void DgvDetalleVta_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", cb.Value.ToString());
        command = new SqlCommand(
                 "SELECT Precio FROM Producto WHERE Nombre = @Nombre", conexion.conexion);
        adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        tabla = new DataTable();
        adaptador.Fill(tabla);
        dgvDetalleVta.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Column5"].Value = 
                                               tabla.Rows[0]["Precio"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Start by correcting this error: The `sender` is not the cell but the whole DGV. So the cast is null. You can access the cell by the e.Row/ColumnIndex..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the CellEndEdit event handler to grab the combobox value after the edit is ended. You will need to cast the row and cell as a DataGridViewComboBoxCell.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        using (var cbx = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnCellName"])
        {
            try
            {
                // Do something with value .... cbx.Value 
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
    }
}
```